# Php my sql insert into does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing with the amazon API. It all works, but when I try to save the server's response to the DB .. the process does not error, but in DB does not save anything.

```
foreach ($offerList as $offer) {
       $buyingPrice = $offer->getBuyingPrice();

       echo("LandedPrice\n");
       $landedPrice2 = $buyingPrice->getLandedPrice();
       echo("" . mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO `price` (mylanded) VALUES ("'. $landedPrice2->getAmount() .'")') . "\n");

       echo("ListingPrice\n");
       $listingPrice2 = $buyingPrice->getListingPrice();
       echo("" . mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO `price` (mylisting) VALUES ("'. $listingPrice2->getAmount() .'")') . "\n");
}
```

The page display 18 times LandedPrice ListingPrice then the cycle is successful. But the DB remains empty :(

Comment: Can you plz mention what error you are facing. Not working means?

Comment: Did/Could you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` somewhere? Any helpful output?

Comment: What is the echo of `mysqli_query`? Is `price` an integer or float? Or is it a `string`?

Comment: What is the return value of mysqli_query(). Try var_dump(mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO `price` (mylisting) VALUES ("'. $listingPrice2->getAmount() .'")')); Refer to php mysqli_query documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: the var dump return NULL

Comment: Just a check: the table is called "price" or "prezzi"? I guess it's just a typo, but...

Comment: If data is successfully inserted in table the returned value is boolean true.  Not sure what null means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function should never return NULL, provided that the `$link` parameter is a correct database connection identifier. I think that your `$con` variable does not identify a valid connection. Try `var_dump($con)`, you should see the problem there.

Comment: yes, function did not see the connection at the beginning of the file .. I replicated and now it works.. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

make sure your connection stablished successfully
try this

```
$SQL=   mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO prezzi (mylisting,mylanded,amlisting,amlanded) VALUES ("'. $listingPrice2->getAmount() .'",0,0,0)') ;
```

you do not need to echo the statement this is an insert query .
you can check for success and failure.. run this as it is and check

```
if($SQL) {
   echo 'insert-success';
 } else {
  echo 'insert-failure';
  }
```

Comment: Please mention what correction OP needed as compare to existing query.

Comment: LandedPrice insert-failure, the var dump return NULL.

This is the query of the table:
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   `mylisting` DEC(6,2),
   `mylanded` DEC(6,2),
   `amlisting` DEC(6,2),
   `amlanded` DEC(6,2)
)";

Comment: this tables is created successfully?

Comment: it may be possible...if other fields value is going to be insert like null then my query will through a warning,

Comment: change the table name from price to prezzi

Comment: try this :...INSERT INTO `prezzi` (mylisting,mylanded,amlisting,amlanded) 
           VALUES ("'. $listingPrice2->getAmount() .'",0,0,0)